# Smart diagram -> constellation diagram: Change direction of the arrows

Tags: smartdiagram

I like to describe an algorithm with its input paramter. I decided to take a constellation diagram. The name of the algorithm is the planet and the parameter names are the satellites. But the arrows are showing from the planet to the satellites although they are input parameters. Therefore I like to change the direction: from the satellites to the planet.

Is there any possibility?

Here is my code:

```
    \smartdiagramset{planet size=2cm, distance planet-text=0.1 ,distance
    planet-satellite=2.5cm} 
    \smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{
        MaxWalkSAT,max\_tries,max\_flips,target,p, gew.Klauseln
    }
```

Thanks for you answers,

Christopher

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure; the TikZ's style `connection planet satellite` can be changed.

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{
  planet size=2cm, 
  distance planet-text=0.1,
  distance planet-satellite=2.5cm,
  /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<-}
} 
\smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{
  MaxWalkSAT,max\_tries,max\_flips,target,p, gew.Klaus
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is the solution I was looking for.