# Draw some circles and arrows

Tags: beamer, diagrams

I work with the latex class `beamer` (`\usetheme{Warsaw}`). In order to say the area C of mathematics was born from the area A and the area B, I need to draw two circles (area A and area B) in right and left with two arrows comes from  them  into the third one (area C) that is under and between them. Is there any idea how to draw it?

Comment: like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252531/smart-diagram-constellation-diagram-change-direction-of-the-arrows ?

Comment: or this http://texblog.org/2015/09/16/drawing-trees-with-tikzpgf-and-lualatex/ ?

Comment: Yes, I have been trying the first one before sending my question. But it seems very complicated for me and still have not understand it.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? So we don't have to start from scratch?

Comment: I use :    \begin{frame}
\smartdiagramset{
  planet size=2cm, 
  distance planet-text=0.1,
  distance planet-satellite=2.5cm,
  /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<-}
} 
\smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{
  A,B,C
}

\end{frame}
 But the result is B-->A<--C I need B and C at the above of A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/283917/36296

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,trees} 

\tikzset{
    >=stealth',
    punkt/.style={
        circle,
        draw, 
        fill=blue!30,
        text centered},
    level 1/.style={sibling angle=120, level distance=1cm},
    edge from parent/.style= {draw=none},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (main) at (0,0) [clockwise from=270]
    child { node[punkt] (1) {A}}
    child { node[punkt] (2) {B}}
    child { node[punkt] (3) {C}}
;

\draw[->] (2) -- (1);
\draw[->] (3) -- (1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 14.1 mm and 10 mm,
                > = stealth',
every node/.style = {circle, draw=blue!30!black, fill=blue!30,
                     minimum size=7mm}
                    ]
\node (b) {B};
\node (a) [below right=of b]    {A};
\node (c) [above right=of a]    {C};
%
\draw[->] (b) -- (a);
\draw[->] (c) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice choice of fill colour! :)

Comment: to be honest, i copy it from your nice answer :-)

Comment: In return I copied the rest of my answer from another question. The colour was the only original thing I contributed :)

Comment: @tarl, here is usual way to say "thank you" with vote answer and accept this one, which is  the best solve your problem :-)